# В какой библиотеке можно постоить нелинейную регрессию?

Tags: python, scipy, sklearn

У меня есть данные (df.head и .tail) [датафрейм](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VRzH8mAaSa7EZAAWPOMoMgIk8psOsWTI/view?usp=sharing):

|  | date | mentor_cnt | mentee_cnt | mentee_dynamic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-02-12 | 2 | 2 | nan |
| 1 | 2021-02-19 | 1 | 1 | 0,5 |
| 2 | 2021-03-06 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-03-27 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 2021-04-10 | 4 | 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2021-04-18 | 3 | 3 | 0,75 |
| 37 | 2022-07-08 | 279 | 368 | 1.319 |
| 38 | 2022-07-22 | 291 | 388 | 1.333 |
| 39 | 2022-08-05 | 341 | 478 | 1.402 |
| 40 | 2022-08-19 | 373 | 521 | 1.397 |
| 41 | 2022-09-02 | 460 | 725 | 1.576 |

Задача: сделать прогноз mentor_cnt на основе mentee_cnt.

Я уже построил нелинейную регрессию, однако она не годится для использования (к тому же подбирать вид уравнения вручную может быть сложно).

Я использовал scipy.optimize, sklearn и scipy.stats.
Какой вариант еще стоит попробовать в моем случае?

P. S. LinearRegression и PolynomialFeatures из sklearn уже пробовал.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from scipy import stats
import scipy.optimize as opt

df = pd.read_csv(...)

# Создание y, x
x_non_linear = df['mentee_cnt'].to_numpy()
y_non_linear = df['mentor_cnt'].to_numpy()

# Разбивка на тренировочную и тестовую выборки
x_train_non_linear, x_test_non_linear, y_train_non_linear, y_test_non_linear = train_test_split(x_non_linear, y_non_linear, test_size=0.2)

def func(X,  b, c):
    return b*(X**c)

plt.plot(x_train_non_linear, y_train_non_linear, 'ko', label='Test values')

x_lin = np.linspace(0, x_train_non_linear.max(), 50)

p0 =[2, 0.8]
w, _ = opt.curve_fit(func, x_train_non_linear, y_train_non_linear, p0=p0)
y_model = func(x_lin, *w)

plt.plot(x_train_non_linear, y_train_non_linear, 'bo', label='Train values')
plt.plot(x_lin, y_model, 'r--', label='Model')
plt.title('Least squares regression')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

x_lin_test = np.linspace(0, x_test_non_linear.max(), 50)
y_model_test = func(x_lin_test, *w)

y_pred_for_test = func(x_test_non_linear, *w)
residuals_non_linear = y_test_non_linear - y_pred_for_test
residuals_non_linear_ptc = (y_test_non_linear - y_pred_for_test)/y_test_non_linear*100

rmse_non_linear = mean_squared_error(y_test_non_linear, y_pred_for_test, squared = False)
mse_non_linear = mean_squared_error(y_test_non_linear, y_pred_for_test)
r2_score_non_linear = r2_score(y_test_non_linear, y_pred_for_test)

print(f'rmse_non_linear: {rmse_non_linear:.3f}')
print(f'mse_non_linear: {mse_non_linear:.3f}')
print(f'r2_score_non_linear: {r2_score_non_linear}')
print(f'mentor_cnt = {w[0]:.3f} * (mentee_cnt ** {w[1]:.3f})')

# проверяем нормальность распределения остатков
stat_residuals_non_linear, p_residuals_non_linear = stats.shapiro(residuals_non_linear)
print(f'Shapiro: stat_residuals = {stat_residuals_non_linear:.3f}, p_residuals = {p_residuals_non_linear:.3f}')

plt.plot(x_test_non_linear, y_test_non_linear, 'bo', label='Test values')
plt.plot(x_lin_test, y_model_test, 'r--', label='Model')
plt.xlabel("mentee")
plt.ylabel("mentor")
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.title(
    f'''LinearRegression predict vs. test values\n
    RMSE_test = {rmse_non_linear.mean():.3f}
    mentor_cnt = {w[0]:.3f} * (mentee_cnt ** {w[1]:.3f})'''
    )
plt.show()

# график для проверки нормальности распределения остатков
res = stats.probplot(residuals_non_linear, plot=plt)
plt.ylabel('Residuals')
plt.xlabel('Excepted normal Value')
plt.title(f'Normal probability plot of residuals\nShapirp: stat_residuals={stat_residuals_non_linear:.3f}, p_residuals={p_residuals_non_linear:.3f}')
plt.show()

# проверка однородности дисперсии остатков
sns.scatterplot(y=residuals_non_linear, x=y_pred_for_test)
plt.title('Predicted vs. Residual Values')
plt.xlabel('Predicted values')
plt.ylabel('Residuals')
plt.show()
```

Результат работы кода:
Модель vs тренировочная выборка
[image: Модель vs тренировочная выборка]
Модель vs тестовая выборка
[image: Модель vs тестовая выборка]

```
rmse_non_linear: 5.507
mse_non_linear: 30.322
r2_score_non_linear: 0.9960486902733482
mentor_cnt = -9.466 + 3.113 * (mentee_cnt ** 0.766)
Shapiro: stat_residuals = 0.981, p_residuals = 0.970
```

Распределение остатков:
[image: Распределение остатков]

Дисперсия остатков:
[image: Дисперсия остатков]

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вывод вашего кода, включая графики. Может у вас не так всё и плохо. А вообще я правильно понимаю, что у вас всего одна фича, в основном равная таргету? И что вы хотите от модели тогда? Сначала нужно понять, что у вас за данные вообще - какие фичи, что они означают. Просто так бросать данные в модели - бессмысленно.

Comment: Так, хорошо. Ну в целом у вас всё неплохо. Тут либо нужно выявлять и выкидывать выбросы перед обучением модели. Либо пробовать модели, не так чувствительные к выбросам. Я бы попробовал `Rige` и `Lasso` для начала. А ещё попробуйте построить распределения ваших фич. Возможно, они имеют не нормальное распределение и их полезно будет, например, прологарифмировать. Всяко бывает.

Comment: Да, собственно к теме вопроса. Попробуйте сплайны разной степени, а вдруг оно: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate/1D.html

Comment: Данные не соответствуют нормальному распределению. Логарифмирование не особо помогает, результаты получаются сомнительные. Кстати, это корректно смотреть не абсолютное отклонение остатков, а относительное? Кстати, есть подход, позволяющий избежать ручного подбора формы уравнения регрессии?

Comment: Много вопросов, а у меня работа )  Дома сам ещё данные посмотрю. Может у вас там вообще временные ряды. )  А других фич нет, только эти? Так то можно ещё в сторону `GLM` посмотреть: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#generalized-linear-models и https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/glm.html

Comment: Вообще главное тут - понять, что же вы хотите то в итоге. Например, `interp1d` даёт практически идеальную интерполяцию, но это на имеющихся данных, не факт, что эта модель хорошо генерализует, может она переобучается наоборот. А так то у вас на картинках и так довольно хорошее попадание модели и проблема разве только в ручном подборе коэффициентов.